# Использование параметра SO_REUSEADDR в TCP-сервере

Tags: unix, c, tcp-ip, сокет, linux

Всем добрый день!
В процессе написания и отладки tcp-сервера столкнулась с несколько непонятным поведением программы : сервер не хотел работать после перезапуска. Нашла информацию, что рекомендуется во всех tcp-серверах перед вызовом функции *bind()* устанавливать параметр *SO_REUSEADDR*, так как возможны случаи, когда дочерние процессы продолжают висеть на обслуживании соединения, в то время как сервер перезапускается, и получается что он пытается использовать уже задейстованный порт.

Переписала с опцией, ошибка пропала, далее возник вопрос - почему вообще так происходит? В моем случае сервер действительно порождает дочерние процессы, однако дескрипторы присоединенных сокетов им не передаются - я закрываю их в дочернем процессе. Дочерний процесс не общается с клиентом напрямую, а пересылает всю требуемую информацию родительскому процессу через локальный сокет, тоесть удерживать соединение при перезапуске сервера он по-идее не может. Основной процесс сервера при перезапуске все эти дескрипторы закрывает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упускаю.

Comment: > рекомендуется во всех tcp-серверах перед вызовом функции bind() устанавливать параметр SO_REUSEADDR

Не рекомендуется.

Comment: @northener, согласно книгам Стивенса, рекомендуется.

Comment: @northerner, а почему не рекомендуется ?

Я всюду в \*nix для сокетов с последующим accept() устанавливаю и вроде работает (никто не жаловался).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут все гораздо интереснее. Когда сокет закрывается, то он переходит в состояние TIME_WAIT и находиться в нем некоторое время. Потому как по этому сокету может быть ещё какая то активность

> "it's possible that some data have
> no been delivered yet, or something,
> so we wait as a cautionous TCP
> implementation "

Поэтому, некоторое время (платформозависимое), этот адрес:порт нельзя использовать, если только не выставить SO_REUSEADDR.

В целом - ставьте и не печальтесь.

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо!